# Javascript jQuery Ajax autocomplete over multiple lines

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have a problem with my autocomplete

PHP File:

```
  while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array( $db_erg, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   echo '<tr><form action="change.php?t=com&id=1" method="post" 
         <td>
         <input type="text" name="dutie" id="file1" value="' . $zeile['dutie'] . '" autocomplete="off">
         </td>
         <td >
          <div class="container" style="width:500px;">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="con_name" value="0Vacant" autocomplete="off"/>
            <div id="list"></div>
       </div>
       </td>
       <td class="uk-text-middle">
       </td>
       <td>
        <a href="#" ></a>
       </td>
       <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
    </form></tr>';
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#con_name').keyup(function(){
       var query = $(this).val();
       if(query != '')
       {
            $.ajax({
                 url:"sql/search.php",
                 method:"POST",
                 data:{query:query},
                 success:function(data)
                 {
                      $('#list').fadeIn();
                      $('#list').html(data);
                 }
            });
       }
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'article', function(){
       $('#con_name').val($(this).text());
       $('#list').fadeOut();
  });
});
</script>
```

So basically i have multiple forms in a table to change the person to a dutie.
The autocomplete works perfectly on the first line but if there are multiple outputs(see in the picture), it doesn't work on the other forms... I think the problem is in the JS but i'm not into JS that much to understand what i'm doing wrong.

[image: Here it is working on the first <form>]
[image: Here it's not working on any other <form>]

Can someone help me so that the autocomplete works on every field?

Comment: This is because id of all the input text boxes are same.

Comment: is it possible to change that, so if i add another charge, that the fields adapt automatically?

Comment: `is it possible to change that` - it's imperative you change that ... you need unique ID's or use some other method to distinguish between instances

Comment: i understand that but i had to copy - paste the js file over and over again and adapt it.. is there a way to work that out in an easier way with the JS file?

Comment: replace id with class and where ever you use '$('#con_name')' replace  with `$('.con_name')`

Comment: Add a class to your dutie text box and use this class name for keyUp. Generate unique-ids using index value like con_name-1,con_name-2.... in while loop. Declare a global variable to hold id of keyUp element and use this global variable to set the value to element

Comment: Alright, seems to work better.. but now when i just change the the #con_name to .con_name everywhere it just shows up on the first <form>  if i change the #list (where the autocomplete should show up) it shows up on every <form> and not just on the one i'm typing on

Comment: The element with id list is part of your html? If yes, then make its id in the format <<dutie-id>-list> and call the same in success callback. For example the id of 2nd list div should be like con_name-2-list and you can call fadein() as $('#'+globalvar+"-list").fadeIn();

Comment: yes, it's the <div id="list"</div> part, i changed it to .list as well but now tje autocomplete shows up on everyform and when click on it, it fills up every form with the autocomplete too..

Comment: @Damon updated the above comment. If it feels like too much code, then you can also use using jquery next() or child based on your textbox.

Comment: @Rajashekhar alright, i'm getting where you are heading.. give me 2 min i'm trying it out

Comment: @Rajashekhar it doesn't work, i made it so that the id="con_name-x-list" on the forms(x is counting up every form) but in js it doesnt work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, added  sample code for your problem in  jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/0ur28asz/1/

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" id="text-1" class="text-box">
    <div id="text-1-list" class="article"></div>
 </form>
 <form>
    <input type="text" id="text-2" class="text-box">
    <div id="text-2-list" class="article"></div>
 </form>



 var boxID="";
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.text-box').keyup(function(){
           boxID = $(this).attr('id');
           $('#'+boxID+'-list').fadeIn();
           $('#'+boxID+'-list').html("data select");
       });

       $(document).on('click', '.article', function(){
            $('#'+boxID).val($(this).text());
            $('#'+boxID+'-list').fadeOut();
        });
   });
```

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work... and i dont know if you didnt see it but i need to use ajax, you don't included that, maybe i intergraded it wrong

Comment: @Damon this is a sample code. I have hard coded html data here. You can include ajax in place of hard coded data.